# CSS layered background effect

Tags: css, z-index, background-image

I can't think of a better way to ask this question so I'll just ask it outright. Does anybody know how to achieved the layered background effect at http://petenelson.co.uk? Is there perhaps a plugin to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **parallax effect**
so just google for jQuery Parallax plugin and you will dosens of them.

The rule of thumb is that you have different elements with different z-index that move with different speed during the page scroll event.

If you take a look at this demo page http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/ you will see in the code that it includes:

`<script src="scripts/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>`

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav').localScroll(800);

    //.parallax(xPosition, speedFactor, outerHeight) options:
    //xPosition - Horizontal position of the element
    //inertia - speed to move relative to vertical scroll. Example: 0.1 is one tenth the speed of scrolling, 2 is twice the speed of scrolling
    //outerHeight (true/false) - Whether or not jQuery should use it's outerHeight option to determine when a section is in the viewport
    $('#intro').parallax("50%", 0.1);
    $('#second').parallax("50%", 0.1);
    $('.bg').parallax("50%", 0.4);
    $('#third').parallax("50%", 0.3);

})
```

Here are some useful links:

- http://medleyweb.com/web-dev/15-useful-jquery-parallax-plugins-and-tutorials/
- http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/07/parallax-scrolling.html

---

**UPDATE:**

The parallax effect can be used not only with scrolling. Actually it's up to your imagination and creativity. For example if you move the mouse over the image on this parallax plugin demo http://stephband.info/jparallax/#parallax you will see that the layered images are moving with different speed.